# Conversion of Arrays into Matrix?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, arduino-ide, arduino-leonardo

I'm going through problem in Arduino code. I have three Arrays and want to convert them into a matrix. I have tried hard but couldn't solve issue.

```
float lb1[24]={1580,480,1580,1580,580,1950,3125,1625,250,500,250,600,500,1450,1480,630,530,1655,1475,3225,3300,1450,280,1730};
float lb2[24]={1450,600,1700,600,3080,3005,1655,500,250,500,600,350,250,1700,1700,600,1625,250,1405,3255,4455,1800,500,1450};
float lb3[24]={500,500,600,600,380.3005,3155,530,400,400,600,350,250,250,500,500,250,1655,1655,3155,2130,250,150,250};
float Loadbase,Loadshift;

void setup() {
    for (int i=0;i<24;i++){
        Loadbase={lb1[i],lb2[i],lb3[i]}; 
    }
}

void main() {
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use two dimensional array directly? Anyway, `Loadbase` is not an array. The `==` is equality operator. You should start with some `C++` tutorial.

Comment: @KIIV i know the logic how arrays are converted to matrix in Matlab. But Arduino coding is bit different than matlab. please give me some example to solve this issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you want to archieve exactly. I can try to answer it..

Comment: @KIIV i want to get a matrix of (3*24) from three arrays.

Comment: Google "c multidimensional array".

Comment: This is your third general programming question (not specific to Arduino) and the third time we've told you this is off-topic. Don't you care about the site rules?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a generic programming problem totally unrelated to Arduino.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two dimensional arrays in C++ (directly):

```
float matrix[3][24] = {
    {1580,480,1580,1580,580,1950,3125,1625,250,500,250,600,500,1450,1480,630,530,1655,1475,3225,3300,1450,280,1730},
    {1450,600,1700,600,3080,3005,1655,500,250,500,600,350,250,1700,1700,600,1625,250,1405,3255,4455,1800,500,1450},
    {500,500,600,600, 380.3005 ,3155,530,400,400,600,350,250,250,500,500,250,1655,1655,3155,2130,250,150,250}
};
```

Two dimensional array indirectly (array of pointers):

```
float lb1[24]={1580,480,1580,1580,580,1950,3125,1625,250,500,250,600,500,1450,1480,630,530,1655,1475,3225,3300,1450,280,1730};
float lb2[24]={1450,600,1700,600,3080,3005,1655,500,250,500,600,350,250,1700,1700,600,1625,250,1405,3255,4455,1800,500,1450};
float lb3[24]={500,500,600,600,380.3005,3155,530,400,400,600,350,250,250,500,500,250,1655,1655,3155,2130,250,150,250};
float * matrix[3] = {lb1, lb2, lb3};
```

If you want two dimensional array with copies of lb1/lb2/lb3:

```
float matrix[3][24];
for (int i = 0; i < 24; ++i) {
    matrix[0][i] = lb1[i];
    matrix[1][i] = lb2[i];
    matrix[2][i] = lb3[i];
}
```

Btw: you were saying something about "mistakes" if I split definition on more lines, but guess what:
`float lb3[24]={500,500,600,600,  380.3005  ,3155`. This is a valid float number, but you have only 23 items then.

If you use at least space as a number separator, it can't be even compiled:

```
float lb3[24] = { 500, 500, 600, 600, 380. 3005, 3155, 530, 400,  400, 600, 350, 250, 250, 500, 500, 250, 1655, 1655, 3155, 2130, 250, 150, 250};
```

Comment: I need this type of stuff, i am giving you material from your answer. but is not working. and giving error."Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560".  float lb1[24]={1580,480,1580,1580,580,1950,3125,1625,250,500,250,600,500,1450,1480,630,530,1655,1475,3225,3300,1450,280,1730};
    float lb2[24]={1450,600,1700,600,3080,3005,1655,500,250,500,600,350,250,1700,1700,600,1625,250,1405,3255,4455,1800,500,1450};
    float lb3[24]={500,500,600,600,380.3005,3155,530,400,400,600,350,250,250,500,500,250,1655,1655,3155,2130,250,150,250};
    float * matrix[3] = {lb1, lb2, lb3};

Comment: @HafeezAhmadFiiZue  My code is tested. However your code pasted here is full of extra characters (and those are invisible in Arduino IDE) that can't be compiled. Some kind of zero width spaces.

Comment: in next comment i will paste the code please check it once again,  for arduino mege 2560 in arduino IDE. it is giving error,"Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560".

Comment: float lb1[24]={1580,480,1580,1580,580,1950,3125,1625,250,500,250,600,500,1450,1480,630,530,1655,1475,3225,3300,1450,280,1730};
float lb2[24]={1450,600,1700,600,3080,3005,1655,500,250,500,600,350,250,1700,1700,600,1625,250,1405,3255,4455,1800,500,1450};
float lb3[24]={500,500,600,600,380.3005,3155,530,400,400,600,350,250,250,500,500,250,1655,1655,3155,2130,250,150,250};
float * matrix[3] = {lb1, lb2, lb3};

Comment: Please **do not** post code in comments. If you need to post code please edit your question and use a proper code block (indent it 4 spaces).

Answer (score 0):

Check this code with slight amendments:

```
float lb1[24]={1580,480,1580,1580,580,1950,3125,1625,250,500,250,600,500,1450,1480,630,530,1655,1475,3225,3300,1450,280,1730};
float lb2[24]={1450,600,1700,600,3080,3005,1655,500,250,500,600,350,250,1700,1700,600,1625,250,1405,3255,4455,1800,500,1450};
float lb3[24]={500,500,600,600,380.3005,3155,530,400,400,600,350,250,250,500,500,250,1655,1655,3155,2130,250,150,250};

void setup() {
int loadbase[3][24] = {{lb1}, {lb2}, {lb3}};
void main()
{}
```